# Django cannot create a new project

Tags: python, django

I have installed python and django, when i run this command

```
django-admin startproject testproject
```

The command run well but it does not create any folder with the name (testproject) or files. and there is no error messages.

I am using Python 3.11.2 and Django v. 4.1.7

I tried to run the command and I expected it will create a project but it does not create the folder and no error messages. When I run the command again it give this `CommandError: 'D:\DjangoProjects\testproject' already exists` but there is NO folder in the directory.

Comment: are you running this command in you IDE shell or gnome-terminal?

Comment: Run as `django-admin startproject testproject -v2` (verbose level 2) and it should tell you which directory and files are created.

Comment: "D:\DjangoProjects\testproject": please triple check the folder: correct drive, folder and subfolder. Because the error message comes from the OS (Windows) failing to create the folder, which gets caught by Python and then by Django.

Comment: I am running in windows CMD

Comment: I tried to check the drive, folder, subfolders but there is no such folder name, also i tried to uninstall python and Django and reinstall but the problem is the same.

Comment: Does `D:\DjangoProjects` exist?

Comment: Well, I scanned the drive and there is folder in local disc C: called VTRoot, this folder has subfolders named HarddiskVolumes, there i found the projects. I do not know the VTRoot folder means what, and it is a hidden folder, I wonder that i choose drive D to create a project, but project created in drive C:VTRoot/.. How is this possible.

Comment: Yes D:\DjangoProjects exists

Comment: I found out it is caused by Antivirus. This is a Comodo Feature. thanks all.

Comment: Oh wow. Glad you found out. Anti-virus are often the last thing on my mind when debugging things.

Answer (score 0):

This is for anyone has the same problem, In my case it was Antivirus feature, so i disable it and every thing goes well.